# Why is my div disappearing when iframe is added to the page?

Tags: css, iframe

I have nested divs (2 inside of 1). The first inside div contains an iframe. When I add the second inside div it doesn't show on the page. When I remove the first inside div containing the iframe the second one now shows. Can't figure this out after many tries. Help appreciated.

**Link to page with div containing iframe:**

http://williampevear.com/redesign/boston-dental-clinic-3.php

**Link to page with iframe commented out--now second div is showing:**

http://williampevear.com/redesign/boston-dental-clinic-2.php

Comment: DO NOT LINK to your page! Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

U close the `</iframe>` wrong.. you have it as `</frame>` and its breaking the rest of your code

Comment: Sheesh--thank you. Amazing that the iframe worked with the error prior to adding the other div. How stupid of me to miss that. Much appreciated!